# Question about Real analysis by G.B.Folland theorem 5.8

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

[Folland real analysis theorem 5.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4HyL.png)

Here's the question about proving that the (operator) norm of f is 1. ||f||≤1 is direct from the Hahn-Banach theorem, but I don't know if I am right about proving that ||f||=1.

If we let y* be an element of M which makes ||x-y||=δ, then it follows that |f(y*-x)|=|f(-x)|=δ, and we get |y*-z|=δ, so ||f||≥1.

Am I right? I feel like I am missing something simple..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your $y$ need not exist. (It exists in finite dimensional case, but not in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $y$ need not exist. (It exists in finite dimensional case, but not in general).

For a correct proof choose a sequence $(y_n)$ in $M$ with $\|x-y_n|| \to \delta$. Such a  sequence exists by definition of infimum. Now we get $|f(y_n-x)|=\delta$ and $\frac {y_n-x} {\|y_n-x\|}$ is a unit vector. So $\|f\| \geq f(\frac {y_n-x} {\|y_n-x\|})$. Let $n \to \infty$ to  finish.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I'm sorry but can I ask one more question? Below problem was one of my undergraduate analysis exam problems.  Why Can't I use this for existence of y in my original thought?                    
[   Consider  nonempty  subsets  A  and  B  in  a  metric  space  (X, d).   We  deﬁne  distance  between  two  nonempty sets  by
d(A, B)  :=  inf {d(a, b)  :  a  ∈  A,   b  ∈  B}.
(a)  (7  pts)  If  X  =  {x}  (X   contains  only  one  point)  and  Y    is  closed,  prove  that  d(X, Y )  =  d(x, y)  for  some  y  ∈  Y .]

Comment: That is  a false  statement. It is true if $C$ is compact but just closed is not enough.  It is true for all closed sets $C$ if you are working in an Euclidean space. @MSLee

Comment: Oh, that's why I was confused. Thanks to you, I know one more thing :)